# Brew + suite-sparse421

Tags: macos, homebrew, suitesparse

I have installed `brew` on OSX and I have installed successfully several things.

However when I try to install `suite-sparse421` (hard constraint on the version):

```
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew install suite-sparse421
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "suite-sparse421" 
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

Running `brew doctor` shows no problem (`Your system is ready to brew.`)

Running `brew update` shows no problem (`Already up-to-date.`)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this

[https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/suite-sparse.rb](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse-4.5.3.tar.gz)

Homebrew-science/suite-sparse.rb has updated it url  to download the 4.5.3 package, "http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/SuiteSparse/SuiteSparse-4.5.3.tar.gz"

If you want a specific version , why not download and build on your own.
The commands to build are pretty self explanatory there in the rb script.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error message there’s no formula named `suite-sparse421`. There’s nothing wrong with your Homebrew installation; it just doesn’t exist. See [this other SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158763/735926) on how to install a previous version of a formula.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous right answers, the formula `suite-sparse421` [was removed](http://www.braumeister.org/repos/Homebrew/homebrew-science/formula/suite-sparse421). And all archived versions of SuiteSparse are listed on the [official website](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/SuiteSparse/).